# Simple file reading throws error in Xamarin project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In this example I try to make the most simple file reading in c# work but it throws me these two errors:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'D:\test.txt' is denied.'
>
> An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code.

My problem is that running Visual Studio with administrator privileges won't solve my problem, then I need to make a Xamarin UWP application from it. My other problem is, that I will have to perform multiple tasks with which I have the very same problem. These tasks are for example using a POS printer.

When I tried to use the printers code that worked fine with windows forms in my c# code in the Xamarin app it threw the same error as the one for the simple file reading.

I already tried to run Visual Studio with administrator privileges, that did not solve my problem.
I also tried to use

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

in app.manifest still got the same error

The code: I know this is not a lot, but every other parts are running fine untill these two lines.

```
public void testFunction()
{
  string tmpFile = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\test.txt");
}
```

The part where I got the error for the printer:

```
PrintExtensions.Print(BytesValue, "\\\\DESKTOP-7LVN776\\EPSON TM-T20II");
```

[This is my project structure. You can see I wan't to use the code outside of the UWP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwzkY.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions):

> Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps can access certain file system locations by default. Apps can also access additional locations through the file picker, or by declaring capabilities.

So a UWP app cannot arbitrarily access files on the system that it doesn't have permission for. If you want the app to have these additional permissions, see [this section of the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations).